# Mapping function with multiple arguments in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

It is common to use nested functions in Google Earth Engine to create a function that receives several arguments and can be mapped through an ee.ImageCollection.

Until now I had always done it the following way in the Python API: creating a function that receives the ee.ImageCollection and the rest of the arguments and map the wrapped function internally. Let's take a simple function as an example:

```
def compute(image_collection, band1='B1', band2='B2'):
   def wrap(image):
      A = image.select(band1)
      B = image.select(band2)
      return B.subtract(A).divide(A.add(B)).copyProperties(image)
   return image_collection.map(wrap)
```

*Usage:*

```
imageCol2 = compute(imageCollection=imageCol1, band1='B1', band2='B2')
```

But I found another approach in which the wrapped function is returned.

```
def compute(band1='B1', band2='B2'):
   def wrap(image):
          A = image.select(band1)
          B = image.select(band2)
          return B.subtract(A).divide(A.add(B)).copyProperties(image)
   return wrap
```

*Usage:*

```
imageCol2 = imageCol1.map(compute(band1='B1', band2='B2'))
```

Is there any difference between the two approaches?

Is one of them more computationally efficient or more convenient for some reason?

Is it the same in the JavaScript Code Editor?

Comment: They're identical because the client-side version is only run ~once.  The computation description that gets built and sent to the server will be the same either way.  You can also just use a lambda to call a multi-argument version without needing to make another function inside:
`collection.map(lambda img : compute(img, 'B1', 'B2'))`